# what does fscanf being == 1 do

Tags: c, file, scanf

There is more to this code obviously but I am just curious as to what this line of code actually does. I know the while loop and such but am new to the `fscanf()`

```
while (fscanf(input_file, "%s", curr_word) == 1)
```

Comment: Google "fscanf" and click on the first link.

Comment: You should always read the manual for any function you are using (especially ones you're not sure about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf()` returns the number of input items successfully scanned and stored.

as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

> Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

In your case

```
while (fscanf(input_file, "%s", curr_word) == 1)
```

`fsaacf()` will return a value of `1` if it is able to successfully *scan* a string (as per the `%s` format specifier) from `input_file` and put it into `curr_word`.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf(input_file, "%s", curr_word)` reads the input stream `input_file` and stores the next sequence of non spacing characters into the array pointed to by `cuur_word` and appends a `'\0'` byte.  As you can see, the size of this array is not passed to `fscanf`.  This is a classical case of potential buffer overflow, a security flaw that can be exploited by a hacker by storing appropriate contents in the input stream.

After `gets`, the `scanf` family of library functions is the best source of buffer overflow bugs one can find.

It is very difficult to use `fscanf` correctly.  Most C programmers should avoid it.